# Set opacity of VML roundrect element

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, opacity, vml

I'm trying to figure out how to set the opacity of a `v:roundrect` VML element in Internet Explorer 8 with JavaScript. I tried simply setting the `opacity` property directly as well as the attribute with `setAttribute` but neither worked. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a `v:fill` element to the `v:roundrect` and set the `opacity` property ?

```
var vfill = document.createElement("v:fill");
vfill.setAttribute("color",fillcolor);
vfill.setAttribute("opacity",fillopacity);
roundRect.appendChild(vfill);
```